# Adding claims when signing in

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, .net-core

Days I'm strugling with new Authentication in .NET Core 2.2
Here what I've :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/api{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LoginPath}";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/api{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LogoutPath}";
                options.EventsType = typeof(MyEvents);
            });
        services.AddScoped<MyEvents>();
    }

    public class MyEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        public async override Task SignedIn(CookieSignedInContext context)
        {
            // do some checks
            // add cookie to CookieManager >> WORKS WELL
            // add claims to Principal >> NOT WORKING

            if (error) 
            { await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(scheme); context.Principal = null ; }
         }

        public async override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
        {
            // idea here is to check if claims are already set, if not add them
            if (context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
                return;

            // time consuming claims search
            // add claims here : WORKS but only for this instance
         }
```

**Problem**

Adding claims in SignedIn does absolutely nothing, when back in calling method, claims are not set.

Adding claims in ValidatePrincipal only works for the current [Authorize] check. Each time I'm entering this method claims are no more set.

I would like to avoid a time consuming process of searching claims. Is there a safer way to add them once for the session?

Cheers,